# Can anybody write the test cases for sticky note?

Tags: testing

Test cases for manual testing.
Step by step procedure to test this functionality(sticky note) so that it gives desired output.

Comment: Could you add some more details? It's hard to understand what you're asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably that it sticks, stay stuck for awhile, removable (and doesn't leave residue behind), and writable.

Comment: I think this is very clear answer.

Answer (score 0):

if its just the functionalities..

check whether it displays what ur tying in,
check if its saved wen pressing enter,
closes properly,
shows the saved noted wen opened afresh,
can edit previously entered notes,
can b moved form one place to another,
wen restarted it gets displayed at the previous location..